# subquery with dynamic user-defined variable per row

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Weird question, which probably isn't even possible.
It revolves around the views below. As shown in the second view (ambulances_available) I'm trying to get a count of the amount of ambulances that are available based on the first view (ambulances_shift_available).

In all my wisdom (read being a complete novice) I'm using 2 user-defined variables. The date one is easy, but the @shift_id is needed to get the specific count per shift.

On the bottom is a sample return of what I would like to see.

```sql
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `ambulances_shift_available` AS
    SELECT 
        `shifts_options`.`id` AS `id`,
        `shifts_options`.`timeStart` AS `timeStart`,
        `shifts_options`.`timeEnd` AS `timeEnd`,
        `shifts_options`.`locations_id` AS `locations_id`,
        `shifts_options`.`types_id` AS `types_id`,
        `ambulances`.`id` AS `ambulances_id`
    FROM
        (`shifts_options`
        JOIN `ambulances`)
    WHERE
        ((`shifts_options`.`id` = SHIFT_ID())
            AND (`ambulances`.`types_id` = `shifts_options`.`types_id`)
            AND (`ambulances`.`locations_id` = `shifts_options`.`locations_id`)
            AND `ambulances`.`id` IN (SELECT 
                `ambulances_unavailable`.`ambulances_id`
            FROM
                `ambulances_unavailable`
            WHERE
                ((TIMESTAMP(SPECIFICDATE(),
                    `shifts_options`.`timeStart`) BETWEEN CAST(`ambulances_unavailable`.`dateStart` AS DATETIME (6)) AND CAST(`ambulances_unavailable`.`dateEnd` AS DATETIME (6)))
                    OR (TIMESTAMP(SPECIFICDATE(),
                    `shifts_options`.`timeEnd`) BETWEEN CAST(`ambulances_unavailable`.`dateStart` AS DATETIME (6)) AND CAST(`ambulances_unavailable`.`dateEnd` AS DATETIME (6)))
                    OR (CAST(`ambulances_unavailable`.`dateStart` AS DATETIME (6)) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(SPECIFICDATE(),
                    `shifts_options`.`timeStart`) AND TIMESTAMP(SPECIFICDATE(),
                    `shifts_options`.`timeEnd`))
                    OR (CAST(`ambulances_unavailable`.`dateEnd` AS DATETIME (6)) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(SPECIFICDATE(),
                    `shifts_options`.`timeStart`) AND TIMESTAMP(SPECIFICDATE(),
                    `shifts_options`.`timeEnd`))))
            IS FALSE);
```

---

```sql
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `ambulances_available count` AS
    SELECT 
        `shifts_uncoupled`.`id` AS `id`,
        `shifts_uncoupled`.`date` AS `date`,
        `shifts_uncoupled`.`shifts_options_id` AS `shifts_options_id`,
        (SELECT count(*) from (select @shift_id:=`shift_options_id` p) parm, ambulances_shift_available)
    FROM
        `shifts_uncoupled`
```

| 73 | 2023-11-07 | D00 | 4 | 
| 74 | 2023-11-07 | D10 | 6 | 
| 76 | 2023-11-07 | D20 | 5 | 
| 78 | 2023-11-07 | D30 | 3 | 
| 79 | 2023-11-07 | D31 | 2 |

=======================================
Requested edit:

The reason for the variant of `ambulances.id IN (...) IS FALSE` is simple. I wrote it as `ambulances.id NOT IN (...)` and Mysql-Workbench changed it.
Same goes for the `CAST (...) AS DATETIME (6)`. I wrote it as `TIMESTAMP(...)`.

Hope this gives more clarification.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `ambulances` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `licenseplate` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `types_id` int NOT NULL,
  `locations_id` int NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `types_id` (`types_id`),
  KEY `locations_id` (`locations_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ambulances_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`types_id`) REFERENCES `types` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ambulances_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`locations_id`) REFERENCES `locations` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

AND

```sql
CREATE TABLE `shifts_options` (
  `id` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `timeStart` time NOT NULL,
  `timeEnd` time NOT NULL,
  `locations_id` int NOT NULL,
  `types_id` int NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

```sql
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `ambulances_unavailable` AS
    SELECT 
        `shifts_lists`.`id` AS `id`,
        `shifts_lists`.`ambulances_id` AS `ambulances_id`,
        CONCAT(`shifts_lists`.`date`,
                ' ',
                `shifts_options`.`timeStart`) AS `dateStart`,
        CONCAT((`shifts_lists`.`date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY),
                ' ',
                `shifts_options`.`timeEnd`) AS `dateEnd`,
        `shifts_lists`.`shifts_options_id` AS `reason`,
        `shifts_options`.`locations_id` AS `locations_id`,
        `shifts_options`.`types_id` AS `types_id`
    FROM
        (`shifts_lists`
        LEFT JOIN `shifts_options` ON ((`shifts_lists`.`shifts_options_id` = `shifts_options`.`id`)))
    WHERE
        (((`shifts_lists`.`date` = (SPECIFICDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY))
            AND (`shifts_options`.`timeStart` > '21:00'))
            OR ((`shifts_lists`.`date` = SPECIFICDATE())
            AND (`shifts_lists`.`ambulances_id` IS NOT NULL))) 
    UNION SELECT 
        `maintenances`.`id` AS `id`,
        `maintenances`.`ambulances_id` AS `ambulances_id`,
        `maintenances`.`dateStart` AS `dateStart`,
        `maintenances`.`dateEnd` AS `dateEnd`,
        'maintenance' AS `reason`,
        `ambulances`.`locations_id` AS `locations_id`,
        `ambulances`.`types_id` AS `types_id`
    FROM
        (`maintenances`
        JOIN `ambulances` ON ((`maintenances`.`ambulances_id` = `ambulances`.`id`)))
    WHERE
        ((`maintenances`.`dateStart` BETWEEN SPECIFICDATE() AND (SPECIFICDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY))
            OR (`maintenances`.`dateEnd` BETWEEN SPECIFICDATE() AND (SPECIFICDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY))
            OR ((`maintenances`.`dateStart` < SPECIFICDATE())
            AND (`maintenances`.`dateEnd` >= SPECIFICDATE()))
            OR ((`maintenances`.`dateStart` <= SPECIFICDATE())
            AND (`maintenances`.`dateEnd` > SPECIFICDATE())))
```

```sql
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `shifts_uncoupled` AS
    SELECT 
        `shifts_lists`.`id` AS `id`,
        `shifts_lists`.`date` AS `date`,
        `shifts_lists`.`shifts_options_id` AS `shifts_options_id`,
        `shifts_lists`.`nurses_id` AS `nurses_id`,
        `shifts_lists`.`nurse_student` AS `nurse_student`,
        `shifts_lists`.`drivers_id` AS `drivers_id`,
        `shifts_lists`.`driver_student` AS `driver_student`,
        `shifts_lists`.`ambulances_id` AS `ambulances_id`,
        `shifts_lists`.`created` AS `created`,
        `shifts_lists`.`modified` AS `modified`
    FROM
        (`shifts_lists`
        JOIN `shifts_options` ON ((`shifts_lists`.`shifts_options_id` = `shifts_options`.`id`)))
    WHERE
        (`shifts_lists`.`ambulances_id` IS NULL)
    ORDER BY `shifts_options`.`locations_id` , `shifts_options`.`types_id` , `shifts_options`.`timeStart` , `shifts_lists`.`shifts_options_id`
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `shifts_lists` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `shifts_options_id` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nurses_id` int NOT NULL,
  `nurse_student` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `drivers_id` int NOT NULL,
  `driver_student` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ambulances_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=106 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO `ambulances` (`id`, `licenseplate`, `types_id`, `locations_id`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(10001, 'A-123-BC', 1, 1, '2023-10-03 13:53:20', '2023-10-25 01:50:50'),
(10002, 'A-124-BC', 1, 1, '2023-10-03 13:54:44', '2023-10-25 01:51:16'),
(10003, 'A-125-BC', 1, 1, '2023-10-03 13:54:44', '2023-10-25 01:51:16'),
(10004, 'A-126-BC', 1, 1, '2023-10-04 18:42:00', '2023-10-25 01:51:16'),
(10005, 'A-127-BC', 1, 2, '2023-10-04 18:58:58', '2023-10-25 01:51:30');

INSERT INTO `shifts_options` (`id`, `timeStart`, `timeEnd`, `locations_id`, `types_id`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
('D10', '07:00:00', '15:00:00', 1, 1, '2023-10-18 09:42:35', '2023-11-07 13:58:52'),
('D70', '10:00:00', '18:00:00', 1, 1, '2023-10-18 09:42:35', '2023-11-07 13:58:52'),
('A12', '14:00:00', '22:00:00', 1, 1, '2023-10-18 09:42:35', '2023-11-07 13:58:52'),
('A30', '15:00:00', '23:00:00', 1, 1, '2023-10-18 09:42:35', '2023-11-07 13:58:52'),
('A50', '16:00:00', '00:00:00', 1, 2, '2023-11-15 13:30:18', '2023-11-15 13:30:18');

INSERT INTO `shifts_lists` (`id`, `date`, `shifts_options_id`, `nurses_id`, `nurse_student`, `drivers_id`, `driver_student`, `ambulances_id`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, '2023-11-06', 'N30', 1109, '', 1716, '', 10004, '2023-11-16 12:00:41', '2023-11-16 12:00:41'),
(2, '2023-11-06', 'N31', 1133, '', 1719, '', 10006, '2023-11-16 12:00:41', '2023-11-16 12:00:41'),
(3, '2023-11-06', 'N40', 1736, 'xxx', 1338, '', 10003, '2023-11-16 12:01:50', '2023-11-16 12:01:50'),
(4, '2023-11-06', 'N41', 1309, '', 1730, '', 10002, '2023-11-16 12:01:50', '2023-11-27 13:11:50'),
(5, '2023-11-06', 'N45', 1756, '', 1184, '', 10005, '2023-11-16 12:02:49', '2023-11-16 12:02:49');
```

Comment: The user-defined variables evaluation in multiple-table query is not defined. You may obtain correct output - sometimes and in unpredictable execution, also the output may become incorrect in any unpredictable moment again.

Comment: Please update your question with DDL (`SHOW CREATE TABLE ...;`) for the tables involved and some sample data. The 8 criteria used for the overlap between `shift_options` and `ambulances_unavailable` can be reduced to 2 criteria. It seems unlikely that you need microsecond precision with your `DATETIME(6)`. What and how do `SHIFT_ID()` and `SPECIFICDATE()` do? Your `ambulances.id IN (...) IS FALSE` is more typically written as `ambulances.id NOT IN (...)`. I cannot see any need for a user-defined variable to get your count of available ambulances.

Comment: @user1191247 updated the original question with the requested information.
I'm curious how you would change the overlap criteria, and of course if you can help me out with the original question

Comment: @user1191247 Added. I'll look into fiddle. Never worked with it.

Comment: @user1191247 Added, In your fiddle link it states ambulance_unavailable is missing but you have it in there.

Comment: @user1191247 Ok figured the fiddle thing out (somewhat) and edited the one you made. I doesn't give any errors anymore.  Also added the functions for specificdate() and shift_id() 
https://dbfiddle.uk/TJqOcsdW

Comment: I will have a look later but the [final query here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1WudccNL) shows a typical test for overlap between two time periods.

Comment: The `(6)` seems like unnecessary precision.

Comment: Please define `SHIFT_ID()`.  Note that function is totally unrelated to the 'user variable'`@shift_id`.

Comment: Don't use `@shift_id:=` inside a `SELECT`.  It is deprecated and will go away in some future version.

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` defines a `UNIQUE` `KEY`, there is no need to define a `KEY` with the same column(s) as the PK.

Comment: @user1191247 Looked at the overlap test you put in. That works much better indeed. was busy way too much with the overlap both ways to see this one. Thanks!

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using (`SELECT VERSION();`)? I don't think it is possible to share `@shift_id` between views in the way you are trying. There are some errors in the first select in `ambulances_unavailable` . I will try to build up a fiddle illustrating the problem and the solution. What is the reason for passing these variables around using functions, instead of writing _"normal"_ criteria? Both of these functions need to be declared `NOT DETERMINISTIC` to make sure the optimiser does not cache them.

Comment: @user1191247 Version: 8.0.21, changed to `NOT DETERMINISTIC`
Reason is that I have made the ambulance_shift_available is so I can get a list of the ambulances that are not assigned to a shift or are in maintenance, I pass the shift_id to it so it'll give me the information for that specific shift, since we have lot's of shifts and different starting times.

Comment: To be able to assign ambulances I wanted to make a list of all needed shifts with the amount of ambulances available per shift. This is for decision making purposes. Let's say I have 4 available at 7 AM and 1 at 8 AM I want to assign 8 AM first to prevent that one to be assigned at 7 AM and not have anything at 8 AM.

Comment: I guess I could forgo the use of the view and just do normal criteria but having the view work per shift using the function I thought it "should" be easier to just use that.

Comment: You can still use the views but the criteria should be passed in via the where clause. You need to be careful to make sure a nested view does not result in a large temp table being materialised. I think [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/fsgKrfI3) illustrates the issues with the first select in the `ambulances_unavailable` view, unless I have misunderstood your data. You should be using `utf8mb4`, not `utf8` which is an alias for `utf8mb3`. All tables should probably be `InnoDB`, currently `shifts_lists` is `MyISAM`.

Comment: Here's an updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uLXSMWis) that I had a quick play with. It's tricky to do anything with it, without having some usable test data. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the `ambulances_shift_available` view if it list correctly  all available ambulances for each shift and make sure this view provides `shifts_options.id` as one of its columns, which will be used for joining with shift data.

I created the `ambulances_available_count` view, that should join the `ambulances_shift_available` with the `shifts_uncoupled` or the relevant shift table/view and perform a count aggregation.

```
   CREATE VIEW `ambulances_available_count` AS
    SELECT 
        su.`id`,
        su.`date`,
        su.`shifts_options_id`,
        COUNT(asa.`ambulances_id`) AS available_ambulances_count
    FROM
        `shifts_uncoupled` su
    LEFT JOIN
        `ambulances_shift_available` asa ON su.`shifts_options_id` = asa.`id`
    GROUP BY
        su.`id`, su.`date`, su.`shifts_options_id`;
```